# Can any compilation tools generate .buildinfo info by default or needs some flags?

Tags: debian, security, compiling

Common compilation tools like make, cmake, premake, gmake, rake etc. generate buildinfo files by default or support for them is missing ?  Or if they have support, then maybe needs some flags to make sure that .buildinfo files.

I am looking at three tools at the moment -

a. `make`
b. `cmake`
c. `premake`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

buildinfo files are generated by `dpkg-genbuildinfo` on Debian systems, build tools aren't involved. See [the manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dpkg-dev/dpkg-genbuildinfo.1.en.html) for details.